# Is there any way to get correct word from long word with too many vowels

Tags: typescript

I have a function that's passed a text variable as argument the argument contains a long word that contains the correct word I want to extract the correct word from the word with too many vowels as shown below the code.

```
   import assert from "assert";

    function translate(text: string): string {
// your code here
    return text;
   }

   console.log('Example:');
   console.log(translate('hieeelalaooo'));

   // These "asserts" are used for self-checking
   assert.equal(translate('hieeelalaooo'), 'hello');
```

Comment: I only want to retrieve hello thank you.

Comment: That was not the question. What's the logic for getting `hello` from your string?

Comment: function translate(text: string): string {
    // your code here
    let one = text.match(/[he]/g).filter(function(item,pos,self){
    return text.indexOf(item) == pos
})

let two = text.match(/l/g)


let three = text.match(/o/g).slice(1,2)
let result = one.join("").concat(two.join("").concat(three.join("")))
return result;
}

console.log('Example:');
console.log(translate('hieeelalaooo'));
console.log(assert(translate('hieeelalaooo') == 'hello'))

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    function translate(text: string): string {
    // your code here
    let one = text.match(/[he]/g).filter(function(item,pos,self){
     return text.indexOf(item) == pos
    })

     let two = text.match(/l/g)


     let three = text.match(/o/g).slice(1,2)
     let result = one.join("").concat(two.join("").concat(three.join("")))
     return result;
     }

    console.log('Example:');
    console.log(translate('hieeelalaooo'));
    console.log(assert(translate('hieeelalaooo') == 'hello'))
```